# Planning Scalable Web Application Development

Tags: scalability, scaling, web-applications

What language, framework, and hosting considerations should one make before starting development of a scalable web application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The most important consideration is not to over-engineer to the point that it gets in the way of building and launching something.  Analysis paralysis is the single biggest inhibitor to productivity, progress and results.

Yes, do some planning.  Pick a framework.  Perfection in a framework will be impossible to find because it doesn't exist, partially because you don't know what you need until you build it anyways.  Chances are, if you pick something, it will be better than picking nothing.

Yes, try to pick flexible, inter-operable tools for where you see yourself going.

Yes, look for a good built-in feature set where you see yourself going in the next 6-18 Months.  Trying to look beyond that is not really realistic anyways as most projects change so much anyways going towards the first release.

So, pick what you're comfortable with or what is familiar.  Don't follow the crowd, do what gets you the best results, quickest, and often.  Understand that you might have to change in the future.  So, whatever you build now, try to use unit testing so you can re-factor if ever needed.

If what you're building is going to be super successful, it will be a great problem to have, and an easy one to work on once it's making money as you'll be able to get other talent to help you.

Share what you end up picking and why for your situation -- it helps the us learn from you too!

Answer (score 3):

Don't necessarily marry yourself to one language or framework. It may be that some parts of your site work better with different languages and frameworks than others. For example, all of 37signals' sites are based on Ruby on Rails, but they recently wrote a blog post about how the underlying technology of one is actually written in Erlang now because it's much easier to do concurrency that way.

Obviously there's a level of complexity where things turn into a mishmash, but using the right tool for the job — even if that means different tools for different jobs — can simplify things.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly on language, it largely doesn't matter. PHP, Java and .Net being probably the biggest three are all proven in the sense that they run some of the largest sites on the Web so don't listen to anyone who tells you one is more suited than any of the others.

Some might also put Ruby and Django/Python in this list. I have nothing against them but I'm not aware of any big (say top 50) sites using either.

Hosting considerations depend on how low you want to start but basically the order is:

1. Shared;
2. Virtual Private Server;
3. Dedicated.

Scalability will largely be about your application's design than any language, framework or provider. Efficient database schema, efficient delivery and use of Javascript/CSS and in-memory caching are all issues common to any language or framework.

Answer (score 1):

Language - I'd recommend something with good frameworks and good testing libraries like Perl or Java.

Framework - it depends on what do you plan to do. If you start with a hosting that does not allow FastCGI, it is best to avoid such frameworks like Catalyst or Rails. That's why I love CGI::Application (primarily Perl, but ported to other languages too) - it can run as CGI, FastCGI or mod_perl. For development it can be run from it's own web server.

Hosting - nothing is better than you own server. It can be your own server, leased server or virtual server. But you can start with cheapest hosting and when you need more, you should be able to afford it.

Comment: Ruby on Rails doesn't require FastCGI, so I'm not sure why FastCGI support is relevant there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

Start by looking at your requirements (Functional or user defined) (Non Functional - aspects that describe your desired system [link text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-functional_requirement))

Next I would clarify what it means to have a scalable web application.  Define it as test cases that can be clearly tested (must support X page views / second with response time < Y seconds).

Once I had those pieces in place I would look at what type of skills my development team can support (for the intial project and on going maintenance).  Then find some case studies of applications out in the wild that use similar language or framework.  If someone else has made a specific language / framework scale then chances are good that you can too.

Finally go out and look for some hosting providers that support your chosen language, framework and requirements.